# Generic input element for new GeometryField in GeoDjango

Tags: django, postgresql, gis, postgis, geodjango

I have GeoDjango and GeoAdmin up and working, no problems.

I have a models that has a field

```
geom = models.GeometryField()
```

When I create a new record for that model in the admin interface, I get a map, but no way to enter data. I'd expect to be able to choose from Point, MultiLine, Polygon, etc and then draw the shape.

If this is not in GeoDjango, that's fine, I'll have to code it myself. But since GeometryField is a perfectly valid definition, and the Django admin module works fine usually, I'm curious: am I doing something wrong, forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem beautifully by using olwidget:

http://olwidget.org/

By adding this to my Django project and using the instructions to replace the admin widgets with olwidget, it worked right out of the box.

Many thanks to Charlie DeTar for making this available.